# After installing a SSL, got Assessment failed: Unable to connect to the server

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to install a SSL certificate on my domain name.

My server is an Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

But I still have this error:
`Assessment failed: Unable to connect to the server`.

How can I correct this please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

from the failed message, it clearly shows that your server is refusing the inbound HTTPS connection. For me, it worked after I added an HTTPS inbound security rule for my remote Ubuntu server (deployed on AWS), to allow traffic from default HTTPS port 443.

Comment: HTTPS port 443 is also added. But still I am also getting the same error.